# error: unexpected element <queries> found in <manifest><application>

Tags: flutter, build, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I got an error when installing the flutter launcher url I know it's a gradle version problem but I still can't find a solution I've upgraded gradle to the latest version[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5Ecr.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kuefr.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/er0sw.jpg)

I've upgraded Gradle to the latest version,
help me please

````
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.cozy_app">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <!-- Provide required visibility configuration for API level 30 and above -->
<queries>
  <!-- If your app checks for SMS support -->
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="sms" />
  </intent>
  <!-- If your app checks for call support -->
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="tel" />
  </intent>
</queries>
   <application
        android:label="cozy_app"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
        <!-- Provide required visibility configuration for API level 30 and above -->
        <queries>
        <!-- If your app checks for SMS support -->
            <intent>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <data android:scheme="sms" />
            </intent>
        <!-- If your app checks for call support -->
            <intent>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <data android:scheme="tel" />
            </intent>
        </queries>
    </application>
</manifest>
```gradle
````

Comment: can you paste AndroidManifest.xml here? You would find it at <flutter-project>/android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: erro in   /app/intermediates/packaged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:73: error: unexpected element <queries> found in <manifest><application>.

Answer (score -1):

Your queries tag should be inside activity tag.

Comment: can you show me the example? i've change but it's still error